# Googlebot Can Visit My Website But No-One Else, - Struggling To Make Sense of This

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, bind

I am having a problem with my <strike>website</strike> absolute basic HTML page. The nameservers are delegated to the majority of servers, including the AAAA address for the site, ports 53, 80, and 443 are all open to inbound and outbound traffic, the BIND DNS server is set to be authoritative, Apache is the HTTPD server, and there is one domain in the mix: *insurgent.info* [ **2a:00:b900:10a4:1::a** ]...but I have been unable to find a single *test your webpage from other geo-location*, or mobile emulator, site actually able to view, or even access, the webpage (several actually report configuration errors but, frustratingly, do not give any further details); although my HTTPD logs show that googlebot has visited the page on at least 3 occasions.

I have also carried-out the usual *named-checkconf*, *named-checkzone*, *apachectl status*, HTTPD error log checks and found absolutely nothing indicating a problem. Could someone try to visit the site, please (or just send a bot if you think this is some kind of scam =] ), because I absolutely cannot see what is causing the problem, if there actually is a problem, or if my domain simply needs more time to delegate.

Further to the helpful comments I have received on this subject I have just managed to find a website that may be of use to other people with a similar problem: http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone try to visit the site, please?

I visted with an IPv6-enabled mobile data service. The website works fine.

[image: IPv6-Only Website]

> I absolutely cannot see what is causing the problem.

As @grawity points out, IPv6 is far from mainstream and this is unlikely to change in the near future. Anecdotally, my local ISP has been promising the ability to browse IPv6 domains for 5 years now (and 5 years ago, it was "just around the corner"). So you will likely need to maintain IPv4 `A` records for some time to come if you wish to communicate with many computers or services (even if you are just implementing a personal VPN or simple website).

Comment: I would have given you an extra point, in line with Grawity, but I was not aware of the 5 minute "gotcha", so I am not being stingy: I am stil trying to work things out on this site. Anyway, you have a tick for visiting the site (thanks) and thanks, too, for your comments. Now *I* need to work out how to browse the site, seeing as I can not at present.

Comment: No worries. I appreciate any consideration you care to bestow. Thank you =) Regarding browsing the site, that's unfortunate. You may want to look into setting up an IPv6 tunnel, such as those from [Hurricane Electric](https://tunnelbroker.net). That said, that's more geared towards doing IPv6 browsing generally, so I'm not really sure if it would be the best solution to simply checking your website. I have also found IPv6 tunneling a mixed bag in terms of ease of set up (leaning towards the somewhat frustrating end of things).

Comment: Thanks, - looking at ipv6-test.com I can see that the sites that have been submitted, pretty much without exception, all have IPv4 addresses; so I have added those to my domain and will hopefully be able to browse my site again soon (I could originally, but then discovered that my configuration was for recursive non-authoritative and had to change it).

Answer (score 2):

The majority of such "test" sites still lack IPv6 connectivity, and require the web server to be accessible via IPv4. Very often, they also require the *nameservers* to be reachable via IPv4. Google is an exception in that they have been running IPv6 on the backend for *many* years now.

In other words, your servers need to be dual-stack for better reachability. There are no technical problems with the domain otherwise.

(And if you need to run more actual servers than have IPv4 addresses, you can put them behind a single "reverse proxy" – either a local nginx/haproxy instance, or outsource to something like Cloudflare.)

Comment: Thanks, - I actually read an exerpt  shortly after posting, by Cricket Lui, who said that root servers usually lack an IPv6 interface. I am guessing that that has changed a little by now, but I am aware that many VPNs do not fully support IPv6 and I was placing my hopes on most ISPs having dual-stack servers. Evidently the advance of IPv6 is not happening as fast as I thought.

Comment: Root servers support IPv6 just fine – that's not the problem. It's _client-side resolvers_ that usually lack an IPv6 interface.

Comment: Tell me about it: my ISP is an IPv6 ISP (obviously), but I STILL cannot view my website (or, as far as I can tell) any other IPv6 website even though test-ipv6.com reports that my connection is fully IPv6; so I can work with, and use, IPv6 but cannot connect to any IPv6 website or service.

Comment: That means you're able to access _at least one_ IPv6 website (the v6 half of test-ipv6.com), otherwise it wouldn't have been able to detect this at all. So the problems are elsewhere.

Comment: True enough, but I have discovered, and resolved, the problem, so my website is now working as expected. The problem was that I had disabled DHCP in order to use IPv6 statically, due to conflicts with NetworkManager, which was preventing me from being able to set the IPv6 addresses on the linux ethernet adapter. As NM was working at the time of re-enabling DHCP, with the ethernet adapter fully configured, everything has continued to work as expected, even following a reboot of both the router and the webserver. Thanks for continuing to work with me on this.